# How can I get the type of the results of a LINQ query before executing it?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

When `EntityFramework` executes a `LINQ` query, if query returns somethings as dynamic class, I can't get real type of result.

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //and about 1000 other properties
}
```

And 2 derived classes:

```
class RealPerson : Person
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type=RealPerson, Name=" + Name);
    }
}
class LegalPerson : Person
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type=LegalPerson, Name=" + Name);
    }
}
```

My `LINQ TO SQL` query:

```
var lst = 
    EFContext.Persons.Select(item=> new { DynamicClass_Name = item.Name }).ToList();
```

Now for every item in lst, I need to know type of its class to cast this item as that type, but `item.GetType()` returns a dynamic type.
For example assume that one of items of lst is `RealPerson` (called dynamicTypeItem), so if I know type of it is `RealPerson` I will cast this dynamicTypeItem to `RealPerson` using this code:

```
var value = dynamicTypeItem.GetType().GetProperty("DynamicClass_Name").GetValue(dynamicTypeItem);
var result = (RealPerson)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(RealPerson));
result.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(result, value);
```

But I don't know type of this dynamicTypeItem (It has a dynamic type);
How to realize type of every item of lst?
It is very important that the above query selects only and only 1 property (Name property) of entities, so I can't use this code:

```
var lst = 
    EFContext.Persons.ToList().Select(item=> new { DynamicClass_Name = item.Name, Type=item.GetType() });
```

So I need knowing type of every item of lst before converting this item to dynamic type.

**EDIT1**
more explanation: result can't be `Person` because `Person` is abstract. result is `RealPerson` or `LegalPerson`, And when I select only one of properties of `RealPerson` or `LegalPerson` during convertion strongly type to anonymous type the type of original entity is missed.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic type? Dynamic type == `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: Hi, actually, it is still a strong-type, you are using a anonymous type in the query, and if you are using visual studio, you just need to upon the select, then it will should you the result type.

Comment: @findeberg as Panada Zhang mentioned, mean of dynamic type is anonymous type in this question. this expression create a new type at compile-time named "anonymous": **item=> new { DynamicClass_Name = item.Name }**

Comment: This anonymous type has only one property (DynamicClass_Name)

Comment: @Panada Zhang please explain more, I didn't understand what to do! I use visual studio 2010

Comment: @Merta He means that it is not a dynamic type, but a statically typed anonymous type, which it is. Hence my question what do you mean with dynamic type? You are not using them. He means that vs is aware of them being static, ergo the select will show "Select<T> where T is Person".

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework? Why do you even need to cast, you have a setter for all people. Why the @#$% are you projecting your query? It seems like you completely missed the point of ORMs.

Comment: I use EF6.01, as mentioned in a comment under your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to elicit the type from the value of one property of a database table? There is no way to select the type from that, since the type information is not fetched from database.

If you explain what it is you really need we might still be able to help you, but this constraint:

> It is very important that the above query selects only and only 1 property (Name property) of entities

makes what you are trying to achieve impossible. You must select something more from the database.

How I could imaging doing it, although I would have a look at database design first if that is at all possible:

```
public partial class Person {
  public Person() { 
    _dotnetType = this.GetType().Fullname; 
    _dotnetAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly.Fullname; 
  }
  private string _dotnetType;
  private string _dotnetAssembly;
  public string DotNetType { get { return _dotnetType; } set { _dotnetType = value } }
  public string DotNetAssembly { get { return _dotnetAssembl; } set { _dotnetAssembly = value } }
}

// Example usage
var peeps = from person in Entities.Persons
            select new { Name = person.Name, Type = DotNetType, Assembly = DotNetAssembly };

var loadedPeople = peeps.ToList() // enumerate it
                   .Select( p => {
                     var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(p.Assembly, p.Type);
                     var property = p.GetType().GetProperties().First(prop => prop.Name == "Name");
                     property.SetValue(instance, p.Name, null);
                   });
```

I haven't tried this code, but it should work, just ensure that the parameterless constructor in `Person` gets called. The key point is that the database will "lose" the type information, so its better to store it as strings. Do remember that you need to add the columns to the database as well and map them!

Comment: No, I don't want to elicit the type from the value of **one property** of a database table at all! I need to know result is of type `RealPerson` or `LegalPerson`.

Comment: result can't be `Person` because it is abstract. result is `RealPerson` or `LegalPerson`. and when I select only one of properties of `RealPerson`|`LegalPerson` during of converting strongly type to anonymous type the type of original entity missed.

Comment: @Merta Which you cannot know from the name property! A string! One string is everything you are selecting from the database, how could that string tell you what it belongs to?

Comment: I need something like this: `EFContext.Persons.Select(item=> new { DynamicClass_Name = item.Name, OriginalType=??? }).ToList()`

Comment: @Merta But you explicitly state that you only want to select, ie return, one property?

Comment: I mean among 1000000 properties of entity, I need only one of them, but if some additional properties (such as a property containing type of result) should accompany that required property, this additional property is natural and necessary!

Comment: That type information is not stored in the database sadly, it is stored as a mapping so it knows how to translate full entities (ie rows) into their corresponding model types. What you are asking for is not that easily done. The easiest would be just to create a new column, ex "DOTNET_TYPE" which is varchar2 or string, and then use activator to instantiate and instance of that particular type.

Comment: If your entity has 1000000 properties on it then you need to rethink your database design.

Comment: @Craig W, 1000000 columns was an assumption only, that was example of heavy result data...

Comment: @flindeberg thanks! Your explanation was useful and dimensions of problem cleared. I don't know why but I think it's possible! Is there something like creation functions in SQL Server? Is it possible that I have a method in SQL gets me type of resulted entity? If it is possible then I can call that method to get type of entity in my LINQ query :-|

Comment: @Merta I added some info to my answer, does it answer your questions?

Comment: @flindeberg I haven't test your code but it seems to work. But since I haven't modify permission of database I can't add columns to table. Also this approach has some additional costs in database that can slakes performance, whereas our goal is improve performance only!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an XY problem. Your question is, how do I instanciate objects from a table using Entity Frame (AND NOT Linq To SQL), where I have a discriminator?

The answer is simple.

YOU DON'T!

Use [Single Table inheritance](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for your Entity Framework model and your LinqToEntities queries would be pretty simple.

Once you have that, there should be absolutely NO REASON WHAT SO EVER FOR YOUR PROJECTION.

You should be think about objects and not tables with an ORM.

So you could do the following to get all LegalPersons with name 'Alice'

```
var legallyAlices = EFContext.Persons.OfType<LegalPerson>()
                            .Where(x => x.Name == 'Alice');
```

OR

```
var legallyAlices = from legalPerson in EFContext.Persons.OfType<LegalPerson>()
                    where legalPerson.Name == 'Alice'
                    select legalPerson;
```

Comment: I use EF (Not LINQ To SQL) and in ORM, my models are like models of given link ( Single Table inheritance). Your solution is a way for selecting all `LegalPerson`s or have a query on an specific table, but my query can join all tables of my database! So I can't handle this problem by model correction. I need possibility of customize projection of all tables, whether that model mapped to an abstract class or not.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Perhaps you should describe your domain problem rather than diving straight into reflection and anonymous types.

Comment: @flindeberg got the question exactly, maybe reading comments under his answer clear problem and helps us.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a clarification. It looks like you are trying something complicated with Entity Framework (in fact you seem to want to by pass much of it). Your comments note you are trying to improve perf, but you have found that the above "solution" actually is much slower. Reflection often is. I am trying to guide you AWAY from such things, as you will obviously end up with larger memory footprint and much slower perf, than a well architected system.